# Moving block of code in C/C++ (low-level)

Tags: c++

I need to move a block of compiled instructions from its place in memory to another place. The instructions should be compiled from the same program that is moving the block (so precompilation and extracting the compiled bytes afterwards is not allowed).

An example in a form of pseudo-code will be something like:

```
block:
  instruction 1
  instruction 2
  END_BYTE

pointer = &block
while pointer data != END_BYTE
  copy pointer data to new memory address
  pointer++
```

Don't worry about the potential use of referenced data inside the block.

I thought that the easiest way is probably to gather instructions inside a function, get a pointer to the function and then read it until I reach for example some bytes indicating the end of the block (since obtaining the size of a compiled function at compilation time does not seem feasible):

```
VOID block()
{
    // instructions
    __asm {
        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
     }
}
```

However, addressing `&block` to make the copy does not seem to work. Probably there are some compiled bytes prior `instructions` that are messing up. I tried to use a label unsuccessfully. I am also not sure the `asm` block position will be respected by the compiler, and if there is any directive that forces its position.

How can I address this in C/C++? (I am using Windows and x86)

**PD - Actual C/C++ code, rather than abstract ideas, is appreciated.**

Comment: Might not be possible, as code is often loaded into a read-only memory segment to stop these kinds of shenanigans, as they are very exploitable.

Comment: Would those "compiled bytes prior to instructions" happen to be the function prologue? (ie setting up a frame pointer and making space for local variables) You can [tell visual studio to generate a naked function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/naked-cpp?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Read-only means I can read the code bytes. I am not defining where I am moving the bytes to, which ofc must be a writable area

Comment: @Botje - By looking at the opcodes they seem to be like a jump or similar. Maybe the compiler is doing some extra realocations. I will check if naked helps in this case

Comment: Most compiler toolchains allow you to specify a custom linker scripts, or you can figure out where the linker puts your code in the memory by going through the standard linker scripts used by the toolchain.  You can even create read/write text sections, so you can create self modifying executables.  Alternatively you can read the executable file from filesystem.